# IE 6,7,8,9 CSS compatibility Stylesheet

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Developping for all browsers, then fighting for IE compatibility is a well know step in all web developement process.

Not being a web integrator, do you know any generic compatibility stylesheet that are good to include for IE ( In my case I'm only concerned about IE7, but I'll let the question open for all version )

Comment: What exactly are you expecting from such a stylesheet?

Comment: In term of CSS; to make IE behave (as much as possible) like other browsers. In a perfect world, not having to do any CSS hack myself.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to save yourself this pain and write some JS that, upon seeing any version of IE, forced them to either download a better browser or not use the site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

normalize.css is a good reset that addresses a lot of cross-browser issues.
https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is good if you want pre-made components. It is IE compatible.
If you decide to use Bootstrap, its reset is actually adapted from [normalize.css](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L8) (so you won't need both)

HTML5 Boilerplate may also help with some best-practice markup if you're getting started from scratch:
https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate

In particular, I'd recommend using the HTML5BP conditional comments to target specific IE versions, like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

That means in your CSS you can address IE version specific issues with classes:

```
.lt-ie8 .awesome-component { ... }
```

Finally, I would recommend AGAINST using javascript polyfills like CSS3PIE. In my experience they just cause more hassle than they're worth, adding unnecessary markup.

Learn a bit about graceful degradation / progressive enhancement.

Another answer mentioned IE7.js which I believe is fine, though I can't remember how useful it is. You'll definitely need to shim missing JS functions (if you're using js) such as Array.indexOf in IE <= 8. I just found this ECMAScript5 shim which looks pretty good:
https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

Comment: Boostrap 3.x support seems to be down to IE7 if you look at their [bugfixes](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases)

Answer (score 1):

I generally use Eric Meyer's CSS reset (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) which is a good simple starting point.

You may also wish to consider using ie7js (http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/), which uses JavaScript to get different versions of IE to behave better.

Comment: Cool I never though of using Javscript to help normalizing IE-specific behaviors... thanks :)